# Source code listing using \lstinputlisting - prevent other floats splitting it up

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

I am using the **listings** package to take an external PHP file and display it as a code listing in my document. It spans several pages (fine) but unfortunately there are other floats which end up being interwoven between the different pages and the different snippets of the PHP file.

Code used:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=php,caption={PHP code snippet A},label=listing:codeA.php]{./codeA.php}
\global\csname @topnum\endcsname 0
```

Is there any way to prevent other floats (figures) messing up this code listing? Any help appreciated

Comment: you seem to be setting topnum to 0 after the listing don't you want to set it before? but anyway rather than do that, just put `\clearpage` before the listing to flush any floats

Comment: Thanks, the `\clearpage` before the listing did the job nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `\clearpage` before the listing to flush any floats.

Answer (score 1):

use the optional argument `float`:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=php,caption={PHP code snippet A},
                 float, label=listing:codeA.php]{./codeA.php}
```